Given an equivalence relation, How does $[s] = [s']$ imply the existence of some q such that $[s] = [q]$ and $[s'] = [q]$
I am reading a textbook and on a section of equivalence relations, it states that given some set S with equivalence relation $R \subset S \times S$ and given that $s,s' \in S$, if $[s] = [s']$ then there exists some element $q \in S$ such that $(s,q), (q,s'.) \in R$. I understand that if there were to be some element $q$ and like $(s,q) \in R$ why such an end statement is valid, but how do we know that such an element exists??

You can trivially choose $q = s$ (or $s'$ for that matter)

@balddraz So if the question stated that there existed some q such that q $\neq s,s'$ then it would not be true?

@baslerbuenzli No, of course not! That is not what balddraz wrote...

No because if your relation $R$ is the discrete relation $R = {(s, s) \in S \times S}$, $[s] = [s']$ if and only if $s = s'$. So you can't choose $q \neq s, s'$ satisfying your requirement.

Thank you guys!

@baslerbuenzli: Now, you can answer this question yourself and mark it accepted so it is easier for people to see that your query is resolved!

Such is only true when q is trivially chosen to be either $s$ or $s'$
